# Typescript accept and return constrained generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I would like to have a function that accepts either a string or an array of strings. Then it would return the same data type entered in. Here is an example of the code that is currently not working.

```
export default <T extends string | string[]>(s: T): T =>
  Array.isArray(s)
    ? s.map(handleString)
    : handleString(s)
```

Comment: Consider editing your question to include a valid [mcve] of your problem. (From that link: "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it.)

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with function overloading:

```
const handleString = (val: string) => val;

function example(s: string): string;
function example(s: string[]): string[];
function example(s: string | string[]): string | string[] {
    return Array.isArray(s)
      ? s.map(handleString)
      : handleString(s)
}

const a = example('a'); // a's type is string
const b = example(['b']); // b's type is string[]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgQzAEwDYFMDKUBOBLMAcxgF4YAKANwVQC4Zp8iBKUgPhmtQG4AoXgGYBXMMCh5wMdAA8EAWwAOGchHqMChZmtwa%20w0eMkz5S9Cu1NCAbQC6WhjqK29IsRLBTZi5aoeWYAD5%20Grb26kSBwU42MADevDCJMDjoUEI4HgCCODgIAJ4AdHgQ2bl5KswJSYkA-AwFcggK5IgoGNiWldWJ9K1oWI6EFbwAvvygkLAIpJ4mygDkCPPMfBPQMABGM8beZlbzG-N23EA)

[Documentation on overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)

Comment: As an aside, even if you want to do this with generics, you probably can't just return `T` since it can be narrower than `string` or `string[]` such as `"foo"` or `Array<"foo">`.  Unless the `handleString()` truly is an identity function, `example("foo")` is not guaranteed to return `"foo"`, which is what the compiler will infer it to be.  So you'd have to write `example<T extends string | string[]>(s: T): T extends string ? string : string[]` and end up using assertions or an overload to get *that* to compile.